# How to inflate Images in View inside Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

**The idea**

I'd like to have my user to collect items, which will get displayed inside a View within a custom Adapter of a ListView.
This Adapter gets the data from a List
where Banana has the following data model:

- String title
- String description
- String extra
- Int nr
- Int max
- String url

I want my View to display 2 different types of my image, one type is the already collected amount of bananas which will get a alpha= 1, and the other type is a imageview with a alpha = 0.5f (basically the non collected amount). After 4 images (fixed value) I want my view to change the row and display another row of images until it reaches again 4 items. To get that clear I attached a picture of the idea:

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba8Hq.jpg)

** ADAPTER.XML **

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip" >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title Text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"


        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_title" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_range"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RANGE: NOW / MAX"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_desc" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/icons"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
    android:src="drawable/ic_error"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_text_layout"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VIP_ViewPager_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

** JAVA CODE ** feel free to convert to Kotlin

```
public class BananaAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Banana> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Canana> bList;
    View mView;

    public xCardsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Banana> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        bList = list;
    }


        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_banana,parent,false);

        // SET TEXT HERE
        ...
        // SET TEXT HERE

        // Get to the images

        for(int i=0;i<list.getMax;i++) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
        ImageView imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager_ImageView);
        imageView.setAlpha(1);

        }




        return listItem;
    }
}
```

Until here this should work, but now I'm a bit insecure how to check if I have reached 4 items and at the same time, check when I have to switch from my alpha=1 (collected items) to alpha=0,5 (non collected items).

Is this the right way when I'm working with a View here or should I use something else instead?

Thank you